# How to use the annotation @PowerMockIgnore running unit tests?

Tags: java, junit, powermock, powermockito

I am having an issue using PowerMockito when running unit tests with JUnit.

This is the error that I don't manage to resolve :

> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1
> counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions Two classes have the same XML
> type name "myType". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign
> different names to them.
>
> this problem is related to the following
> location: at mypackage.packA.myType ...
>
> this problem is related to the following location:
> at mypackage.packB.myType ...

I tried using the anotation `@PowerMockIgnore` which did reduce the number of occurences for this error, but I am still stuck with 3 packages.

Here is the code I use :

```
@PowerMockIgnore({
   "mypackage.packA.*", 
   "mypackage.packB.*"
})
public class TestClass { }
```